# error testing API POST via Postman and Curl

Tags: api, curl, postman

[image]
I am getting the following error when trying to test the API POST via Postman. Please can someone guide me the right way to setup an API call?

Comment: No!  You cannot post images of the code.   To test you code I need to be able to copy it and test.  I am NOT going to retype your code.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to encode to `Base64 format` the API Key and API secret part.
it help to little bit of protection instead direct text.

> Base64 (`API Key` `:` `API Secret`)
>
> Authorization: Basic `Base64 result`

Example:

API Key: bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH

API Secret: pQaE-ceDi3nFz

encode base 64(bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH`:`pQaE-ceDi3nFz) -> YkhScFkzVnNkSHd1WTI5dGNIOnBRYUUtY2VEaTNuRno=

> don't miss `:` between `API Key` and `API Secret`
> you can test in terminal

```
echo -n bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH:pQaE-ceDi3nFz | base64
```

[image]

Or [this site](https://www.base64encode.org/)

```
https://www.base64encode.org/
```

[image]

So you can follow this step

### In Postman,

#0 Enter your API URL with POST method

#1 Select `Authorization` tab

#2 Select `Basic Auth` in drop box

#3 Enter you `API Key` into `username`

#4 Enter you `API Secret` into `password`

Postman will encode automatically with `base64` format
If you click `Headers` tab, can see it.

[image]

[image]

### In curl,

if you click `</>` icon in Postman (at right top area),it will shows curl command.
you can copy it and pasted at terminal then run it,

[image]

[image]

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://your-api-url' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YkhScFkzVnNkSHd1WTI5dGNIOnBRYUUtY2VEaTNuRno='
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for taking this much effort to help...I was able to follow your guidance and used the following Curl command - but now I am getting "insufficient credit message" which probably means that I need to buy more credits but the website does not offer any way to add more credits...I will try to contact them. thanks again so much.

Comment: You are welcome, If you success testing, give me a thumbs up in my answer.